# colorPrimaryDark(statusBarColor) works only in the child PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, styles, statusbar

How to set the statusbar color in all activities? AppCompat I dont use, android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds -> true - doesn't help

I run on meizu mx4, android 5.0.1

v21\styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ff191919</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff222222</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff191919</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff6666ff</item>
</style>
```

[>SCREENSHOTS<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuCOH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

You should test it on other mobile, because meizu has customed some features.

Comment: here's what happened - [screenshot](http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2016-02/07/me3r797nu8hv.jpg)

Comment: You can refer demo in http://open-wiki.flyme.cn/index.php?title=Flyme%E7%B3%BB%E7%BB%9FAPI.It seems that flyme use background of toolbar as statusbar backgroundcolor.You can try to setbackground on Toolbar and set right background on childview of toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Android is and will continue to be in the near future fragmented in its OS distribution among devices. So with your app you miss all of the iOS users and to lose even more potential clients, you don't target older devices?

My suggestion - use AppCompat. Will save you lots of trouble.